# Comparing two floats

Tags: php, comparison

```
$a->b = 7.56704843521;
$a->c = 7.56704843521;
```

But

```
$a->b == $a->c
```

returns false.

How can that be?

Even when doing `floatval($a->b) == floatval($a->c)` is false, and it should not be necessary anyway when using type-independent comparison "==" instead of "===".

Full code is

```
$a->b = 7.56704843521;
$a->c = 7.06704843521+0.5;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Works fine for me! Please show us your full code! See: http://3v4l.org/EHS23

Comment: Read the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#language.types.float.comparison) for details on why you shouldn't use `==` to compare floats, and how you should compare floats: `$epsilon = 0.0000001;

if(abs($a->b-$a->c) < $epsilon) {
    echo "true";
}
` [demo](http://ideone.com/oeejDZ)

Comment: `echo sprintf("%.20lf", 7.06704843521+0.5);` <- And then you compare the numbers with your eyes

Comment: so for my usecase (comparing geo-latitude) it's ok to compare intval() as it seems?